# Symfony2 Advanced operations on Form Field to set user roles

Tags: php, forms, symfony, drop-down-menu, doctrine

I'm actually developing an application in Symfony2.
I've already built a weel working system of authentication with different roles, setting the structure of my tables according to the suggestion by the official documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

I have two page that using a Form permits me to create a new user and edit the existing users and now **I need to implement a form field (choice) to select the role associated to the users.**
Anyway I found some difficults due this scructure:

This is my ORM definition for \Entity\User.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Users")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{

    // Definizione campi

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     *
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
    */
    protected $idAnagrafica;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
    */
    protected $idTipoVisita;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
    */
    protected $attivo;


    // Definizioni delle funzioni Get

    /**
    * @return integer
    */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * @return string
    */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
    * @return string
    */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
    * @return string
    */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        if (null === $this->salt)
        {
            $this->salt = sha512(sprintf('%s_%d_%f',uniqid(),rand(0, 99999),microtime(true)));
        }

        return $this->salt;
    }

     /**
     * @return array
     */
     public function getRoles()
     {
         return $this->roles->toArray();
     }

    /**
    * @return integer
    */
    public function getIdRole()
    {
        return $this->idRole;
    }

    /**
    * @return integer
    */
    public function getIdAnagrafica()
    {
        return $this->idAnagrafica;
    }

    /**
    * @return integer
    */
    public function getIdTipoVisita()
    {
        return $this->idTipoVisita;
    }

    /**
    * @return boolean
    */
    public function getAttivo()
    {
        return $this->attivo;
    }

    // Funzioni di servizio

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
    * @see \Serializable::serialize()
    */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array($this->id,));
    }

    /**
    * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
    */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list ($this->id,) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    // Definizione delle funzioni Set

    /**
    * @return void
    */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        $this->roles = null;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set idAnagrafica
     *
     * @param integer $idAnagrafica
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIdAnagrafica($idAnagrafica)
    {
        $this->idAnagrafica = $idAnagrafica;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set riferimento idTipoVisita
     *
     * @param integer $idTipoVisita
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIdTipoVisita($idTipoVisita)
    {
        $this->idTipoVisita = $idTipoVisita;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set attivo
     *
     * @param boolean $attivo
     * @return User
     */
    public function setAttivo($attivo)
    {
        $this->attivo = $attivo;
        return $this;
    }

    // Funzioni advance user interface

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->attivo;
    }


    /**
     * Add roles
     *
     * @param \Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Role $roles
     * @return User
     */
    public function addRole(\Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Role $roles)
    {
        $this->roles[] = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove roles
     *
     * @param \Acmee\MyBundle\Entity\Role $roles
     */
    public function removeRole(\Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Role $roles)
    {
        $this->roles->removeElement($roles);
    }
}
```

In the DB is reported like this:

```
ID | USERNAME | PASSWORD | ATTIVO | SALT | IDANAGRAFICA | IDTIPOVISITA
----------------------------------------------------------------------
...| ...      | ...      | ...    | ...  | ...          | ...
```

This is my ORM definition for \Entity\Role.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="roles")
 */
class Role implements RoleInterface
{
    // Definizione campi

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", unique=true)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;

    // Funzioni di servizio

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Funzioni di tipo Get

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @see RoleInterface
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

In the DB is reported like this:

```
ID | NAME | ROLE
----------------
...| ...  | ...
```

In addition the ORM commands generates automatically (without writing a custom class in my Entity folder) for me the table user_roles that manage for me relationship between User and Roles.

```
ID_USER | ID_ROLE
-----------------
...     | ...
```

This is my Form:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/MyBundle/Form/Type/UserType.php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Form\Type;
use  Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User;
use  Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Role;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User', 'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Role'));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Crezione del form
        $builder->add('username', 'text', array('label' => 'Username: ', 'required' => false));
        $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array('first_name' => 'password', 'second_name' => 'confirm', 'type' => 'password'));
        $builder->add('attivo', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'Attivo', 'required'  => false));
        $builder->add('idTipoVisita', 'choice', array('choices' => array('1' => 'Fisiatra', '2' => 'Genetista'), 'required'  => false));
// $builder->add( ***I NEED TO INSERT HERE THE DROPODOWN FIELD TO SELECT THE ROLE*** );
            $builder->add('save', 'submit');
            $builder->add('annulla', 'submit');
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'user';
        }
    }
```

And this is my Controller:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/MyBundle/Controller/UserController.php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Acme\MyBundle\Form\Type\UserType;
use Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    // Funzione per la modifica dei dati dell utente
    public function editAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:User')->find($id);
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user );

        if (!$user) { throw $this->createNotFoundException('Non esiste nessun utente associato a questo id.'); }

        if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
        {
            $form->bind($request);

            // Gestione bottone Annulla
            if ($form->get('annulla')->isClicked())
            {
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('AcmeMyBundle_showAnag', array('id' => $anagrafica->getId())));
            }

            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $user = $form->getData();
                $user->setSalt(md5(uniqid()));
                $encoder = $this->container
                ->get('security.encoder_factory')
                ->getEncoder($user);

                $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt()));
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('AcmeMyBundle_showAnag', array('id' => $user->getIdAnagrafica($id))));
            }
        }
        return $this->render('AcmeMyBundle:User:edit.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),'user' => $user));
    }

    // Funzione per la creazione di un nuovo utente
    public function newAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $anagrafica = $em->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:Anagrafiche')->find($id);

        if (!$anagrafica) { throw $this->createNotFoundException('Non esiste nessuna anagrafica associata a questo id.'); }

        $query = $em->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:User')->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->where('p.idAnagrafica = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery();

        $user = $query->getOneOrNullResult();

        if ($user)
        {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Non puoi accedere a questa pagina perchè esiste già un utente associato a questo id anagrafica.');
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), new User() );

        if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
        {
            $form->bind($request);

            // Gestione bottone Annulla
            if ($form->get('annulla')->isClicked())
            {
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('AcmeMyBundle_showAnag', array('id' => $anagrafica->getId())));
            }

            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $user = $form->getData();
                $user->setSalt(md5(uniqid()));
                $encoder = $this->container
                ->get('security.encoder_factory')
                ->getEncoder($user);

                $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt()));
                $user->setIdAnagrafica($id);
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('AcmeMyBundle_showAnag', array('id' => $user->getIdAnagrafica($id))));
            }
        }
        return $this->render('AcmeMyBundle:User:new.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),'anagrafica' => $anagrafica));
    }

    // Funzione per la selezione della modifica o della creazione di un nuovo record
        public function selectAction($id, Request $request)
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $anagrafica = $em->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:Anagrafiche')->find($id);

            if (!$anagrafica) { throw $this->createNotFoundException('Non esiste nessuna anagrafica associata a questo id.'); }

            $query = $em->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:User')->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->where('p.idAnagrafica = :id')
                ->setParameter('id', $id)
                ->getQuery();

            $user = $query->getOneOrNullResult();

            if ($user)
            {
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('AcmeMyBundle_editUser', array('id' => $user->getId())));
            }

            else
            {
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('AcmeMyBundle_newUser', array('id' => $id)));
            }

            return NULL;
    }
}
```

1)My Form is mapped on the User.php entity and **I do not know how to add a Form field referenced to another entity (Role.php) different form the default 'data_class'**.

2)Another problem is that I need to extract an orray of string (the human readeble name of roles) to display the choices on my Dropdown, but **I need to insert in the DB the related id and not the string**. How can I make this? Have I to done something like this : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html ?

3)I suppose that the **form field instance (dropdown) do not permit me to autamitacally insert a new record with 2 field in my DB** (the association ID_USER and ID_ROLE). What is the best way to make this possible? I suppose I need to exctract the value from my dropdown field and built a query in the controller, but how can I do this?

Thanks a lot for your suggestion,
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In your `UserType`:

```
// ...
$builder
   ->add('userroles', 'entity', array(
      'class' => 'AcmeMyBundle:Role',
      'property' => 'name'
      'multiple'  => true));
// ...
```

In your `User` entity:

```
// ...
public function setUserroles($roles)
{
   $this->roles = $roles;

   return $this;
}

public function getUserroles()
{
   return $this->roles;
}
// ...
```

In your php template:

```
<?php if ($view['form']->errors($form['userroles'])): ?>
   <div class="error">
       <?php echo $view['form']->errors($form['userroles']) ?>
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $view['form']->widget($form['userroles']) ?>
```

**Update:**
In your `User.php`:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="User_Role",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $roles;
```

Comment: Hi, really thx for yor reply. I tried to use this suggestion and in a first test the insert/update operation seemed to work properly. Anyway I found a side effect: When I perform any change of every role of every users, the table USER_ROLE is update but it delete all records about the users with ID = 1 .
I do not find the mistake...

Comment: I render my template in Twig in this way:
`{# src/Acme/MyBundle/Resouces/views/User/edit.html.twig #}<br/>

'{% extends 'AcmeMyBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
'{% block title %}Modifica utente {{ user.username }}{% endblock %}
'{% block body %}
' <header><h2>Modifica utente {{ user.username }}</h2>'</header>
'
 '{{ form(form) }}
' {% if form_errors(form.userroles) %}
  <div class="error">
   {{ form_errors(form.userroles) }}
  <div>
 {% endif %}
 {{ form_widget(form.userroles) }}
{% endblock %}
`

This is a screenshoot of the form: http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/5879/o8s9.jpg

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not able to proper formatting my edit.html.twig in the previus comment. Here you can see this in a best way:
http://pastebin.com/wEjn287n

Comment: For my USER_ROLE table, pratical example:
Suppose my USER_ROLE table is empty. Using the form I edit the role for my user 'admin' (in table USER it have the ID = 1) and I set it to 'Admin' (in table ROLE it have the ID = 1).
At this point my USER_ROLE table contains one record with [id_user]=1 and [id_role]=1 . All OK .

Comment: Now I edit my second user 'Alex'(in table USER it have the ID = 2) and I set his role to 'Normal User' (in table ROLE it have the ID = 2). Now I think I have to found two records in my table USER_ROLE: The first with [id_user]=1 and [id_role]=1 and the new with with [id_user]=2 and [id_role]=2. Any way i find only the second record and the first record ( [id_user]=1 and [id_role]=1 ) was deleted (why?) so I lose the infomation about the role of my user 'Admin'.
Thaks, I hope now you can understand my problem .

Comment: Thaks for your reply, but unfortunately the solution do not work for me. The problem still persist. At any update, my records about the user with ID = 1 are deleted. Probably the program would work fine if I create a fake user ID with ID = 1 and I start to work from the user with ID = 2, but this is a solution I really want to avoid.

Comment: I found the time to return on this project and testing the problem. I discover that the program do not delete the records for my user with ID set to 1 , but it delete the records referenced to the user actually logged! In fact when I was tring update the roles, I was logged in with the user having ID = 1. But if I try to make the same work logged whit another user, tha problem in the same for this user.
Quickly I do not found where is the problem in my code, but I need to re-check it.

Comment: Put your full code (Contriller, Entity, FormType, Template) to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and give me the link.

Comment: Dear freetrace, you are so kind and generous. Here my pastes:
http://pastebin.com/s0WQ81J2 - http://pastebin.com/jLNr34mH - http://pastebin.com/vKipksyR - http://pastebin.com/ijPdysUM - http://pastebin.com/9FrYC3ED - http://pastebin.com/8WjMJkUT - http://pastebin.com/gLhs8Jjt - http://pastebin.com/XryN4GUy . Do you need something else? Now I'm trying to retrieve the Mysql logs to identify if there is a wrong query that causes the error.

Comment: UPDATE: In my mysql log I found this: http://pastebin.com/TpfVJZ0w You can read: " 14 Query     DELETE FROM user_role WHERE user_id = '1' "

Comment: Yes, I defined it and I try it, anyway during my tests I rewrite form 0 this part of my app, and during the variuous editing I also try to remove and rewrite it various time. Unluckly I copied in my paste a version of the file without your update, but I've already tried to use it.
Now I notice that another similar things is in my template that in the paste is different from your suggestion. But I've already tried all. I do not suppose this is the problem.

Comment: Here the new version of my files: http://pastebin.com/jbDd2Mer - http://pastebin.com/XwE3L3W1 - http://pastebin.com/CKB3pcW5 . I tried, and the problem is still the same.

Comment: Yes, I made this. 4 queries were executed.

Comment: @CoyoteUgly Sorry. It seems like i have brake my brain) Try to use `print_r($your_var)` and `vardump($your_var)` to find your mistake. Good luck ;)

Comment: Dear @freetrace, thanks for your support. Now I'm continually testing and analyzing var and logs, but I do not find anything of wrong... I do not understand where is generated the query "DELETE FROM user_role WHERE user_id = '1' " thath causes me the problem...

Comment: I suppose to have delimited the problem: In EVERY form I use(not only for the update opration of my users !! ), when I use the function "$my_var = $form->getData();" the query "DELETE FROM user_role WHERE user_id = '1' " is executed. And I can't really understand why...

Comment: UPDATE: The problem is not limited to the expression "$my_var = $form->getData();" ven If I use "$em->persist($user);" the problem persist